# Is the character "A" a reserved keyword in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, query-performance

scenario:
In Oracle Database, This SQL it's much slower:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_MAIN A, TBL_CHILD_1 B, TBL_CHILD_2 C, TBL_CHILD_3 D, TBL_CHILD_4 E
WHERE A.ID_MAIN = B.ID_MAIN 
AND A.ID_MAIN = C.ID_MAIN 
AND A.ID_MAIN = D.ID_MAIN 
AND A.ID_MAIN = E.ID_MAIN;
```

than that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_MAIN X, TBL_CHILD_1 B, TBL_CHILD_2 C, TBL_CHILD_3 D, TBL_CHILD_4 E
WHERE X.ID_MAIN = B.ID_MAIN 
AND X.ID_MAIN = C.ID_MAIN 
AND X.ID_MAIN = D.ID_MAIN 
AND X.ID_MAIN = E.ID_MAIN;
```

In other words, When I have 3 or more tables joined if I use "A" as an aliasing for "TBL_MAIN" table, it results in a slower query.

It becomes worst when I added more tables in an inner join with table "TBL_MAIN" AS "A".

What is happening?

Comment: I don't believe you. What does the explain plan show for these two?

Comment: Are you sure the second version with a different alias isn't just faster because of caching?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you run the query with X first, and then with A? (Going in the same direction as Alex Poole with this question.)

Comment: yes @mathguy the same thing happen.

Comment: No @AlexPoole, I've tested with 300 lines each table only, the time was too high. more than 1 minute for this simple query with "A" as a aliasing.

Comment: Can you create [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And also include your exact Oracle version and patch level in the question in case this is a real effect being caused by a bug. If it is reproducible then the execution plans would still be useful.

Comment: Also are you timing how long it takes to retrieve/process the whole result set, or just to return the first page of rows? And if the 'A' version takes more than a minute (how much more?), how long does the 'X' version take, and then hoe long does the 'A' version take when run again?

Comment: The shutdown solve for now, but the 'A' version was 99% slower @AlexPoole

Comment: I just don't believe this has anything to do with the choice of alias. Show us an execution plan and we can tell for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself!
Now the two SQL has the same time, just a little faster like @wolφi said.

This scenario was going on for two days, but now its normal.

I believe after a shutdown the database became normal.

An interesting thing about this is when the problems were happening, SQL Tuning Advisor suggested an execution plan for the SQL who make work normal (99,9 % faster). unfortunately, I didn't save recommendation report in that time to show here.

but now without any SQL profile active, the SQL's are with the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. It is part of unary collection operator "IS A SET". In Oracle it is bit complicated, in order to guarantee backward compatibility Oracle has "reserved words" and "keywords". One of them can not be used as identifiers, while others might have special meaning is some contexts - but still can be used as identifiers.

For example you can still use SQL like

```
select * from commit;
or
select * from join where X is a set;
```

words like commit, join, model can still be used as identifiers.

Of course this can not have influence on speed of SQL evaluation. Especially when cursor is reused. It might only slow down speed of parsing.

Comment: I would only add at the end: "But it is still a very bad practice, and it is really hard to see any benefit from using keywords that way."

Answer (score 2):

I found that `X` is actually faster than `A`, but `Z` is even slower:

```
Alias A 60.257 seconds
Alias X 57.747 seconds
Alias Y 58.383 seconds
Alias Z 62.157 seconds
```

To be honest, these differences are to small to prove a difference between the names of the aliases.

I tested it with 5 large tables (tbl_main 22 million, tbl_child 17 million etc). And I changed `SELECT *` into `SELECT COUNT(*)` to make sure all rows are processed. The first execution is ignored to warm the caches. The next three runs are averaged.

```
DECLARE
  FUNCTION test1(c VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    time1 NUMBER; time2 NUMBER; stmt VARCHAR2(3000); n NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    stmt := q'!
      SELECT count(*)
        FROM tbl_main #, tbl_child1 B, tbl_child2 C, tbl_child3 D, tbl_child4 E
       WHERE #.geb_id = B.geb_id
         AND #.geb_id = C.geb_id
         AND #.geb_id = D.geb_id
         AND #.geb_id = E.geb_id
    !';
    stmt := REPLACE(stmt, '#', c);  
    --dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
    time1 := dbms_utility.get_time(); 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt INTO n;
    time2 := dbms_utility.get_time(); 
    return (time2-time1)/100;
  END test1;

  PROCEDURE test3(c VARCHAR2) IS
    ignore NUMBER; seconds NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    ignore := test1(c);
    seconds := (test1(c)+test1(c)+test1(c)) / 3;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Alias '||c||' '||round(seconds,3)||' seconds');
  END test3;
BEGIN
  test3('A');
  test3('X');
  test3('Y');
  test3('Z');
END;
/
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the choice of alias. Queries will run at different times for any number of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It is in 12c.

```
SELECT KEYWORD
FROM V$RESERVED_WORDS
WHERE KEYWORD = 'A'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. A is not a reserved word. If it would be a reserved word, it would raise an error. However to analyze your performance problem, you would need to post the metrics for query execution.